# MemoryStream.TryGetBuffer to get the underlying byte array instead of calling ToArray

Tags: c#, compression, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following code where I am trying to compress the byte[]. Right now I am using ToArray() to return the compressed byte[] but I would like to leverage MemoryStream.TryGetBuffer  to get the underlying byte array instead of calling  ToArray.This will avoid the additional copy of the data in the buffer.

```
public static byte[] Compress(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
        {
            gzipStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        return memoryStream.TryGetBuffer(out ArraySegment<byte> buff);
    }
}
```

I am getting an error in the above code.

Can anyone help me here by providing some guidance?

Comment: You would need to change the return type of `Compress()` to `ArraySegment<byte>`, and return `buff`. The issue is that only part of the internal buffer may be populated, so the implementation is using `ArraySegment` to represent that portion without copying the data.

Comment: You could call [`MemoryStream.GetBuffer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer?view=net-7.0) to get at the underlying buffer explicitly, but you would then also have to use `MemoryStream.Length` to determine how many bytes in the underlying buffer are actually populated.

Comment: Presumably you should just not do it. Its likely that the caller needs a correctly sized array for some follow up task and you then would copy the array for that. So you just push the effort of copying to the caller of the method and you don't gain anything really besides more complicated code.

Comment: You will have to change signature of your method to be able to use underlying memory stream buffer